# TC fails due to Chrome using file I operate on - how to disable it?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have this Selenium Webdriver TC where I download a file, copy it to another location, rename it and fulfill with content.

Test is simple but it fails about 8 on 10 tries due to:

```
SeleniumWithNunit.ModuleName.T4_002_ContactUpload:
System.IO.IOException : The process cannot access the file
'C:\path\uploads\file-2016-01-25.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.
```

It happens just after file is downloaded by Chrome and it starts to "scan" it (probably). It looks like this in browser (mark that blue circle around file icon):

### [image]

I used really ugly timer to wait for it to finish, but sometimes it takes 1 sec and sometimes over 10-15 sec, so the timer is useless.

**Are you aware of any way to disable this functionality in Chrome?**
(I cannot turn off antivirus, even if it triggers the action)

Comment: As far as i know that blue circle comes when the file is downloading. I guess that i not the one which is causing problem.

Comment: When it's spinning around, it is definitely not downloading a thing, file is already on drive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line flag in Chrome to disable this functionality:

```
--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection
```

C# Example:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: How to use it in Selenium Webdriver test? I assume this is a code I would need to "attach" to Chrome's exec, so how to do it on Webdriver level?

Comment: You can use the ChromeOptions class to pass command line arguments to your Webdriver. I updated my answer with an example in C#. Hope it helps!

Comment: Well it seems that the circle is still spinning after all... I'm afraid I will have to live with that nasty Thread.Sleeps after all.